# Ruby on Rails 3 JSON Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am trying to deploy to vexxhost with capistrano and this is what I get at the final step of the deployment process:

```
command finished in 344ms
** transaction: commit
* executing `deploy:restart'

/Users/kleon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse': 743: unexpected token at 'gem 'unicorn', '4.1.1' (JSON::ParserError)

{"cpanelresult":{"data":[{"status":1,"statusmsg":"restart ok"}],"event":{"result":1},"module":"RoR","apiversion":2,"func":"restartapp"}}
'

from /Users/kleon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.0/lib/capistrano-vexxhost/capistrano_integration.rb:118:in `block in cpanel_api2_command'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.0/lib/capistrano-vexxhost/capistrano_integration.rb:114:in `cpanel_api2_command'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.0/lib/capistrano-vexxhost/capistrano_integration.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `invoke_task_directly'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'  
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:171:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:139:in `invoke_task_directly'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /Users/kleon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3_atlnetsolutions/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i am sorry but looks like i cant write the code in the correct way. How do i format the message?

Comment: The JSON looks correct but is the error the single quote on the next line? Also, lines indented with 4 spaces will be formatted as code.

Comment: i believe the response from the server is not correct. Also when i try to run a rake task lets say rake routes or rake db:create i get the following error

rake aborted!

Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe

/Users/kleon/Personal/atlnetsolutions/trunk/railsapp/Rakefile:5:in `require'